# Passing database data to another activity

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, android-intent, bundle

how can I pass an array of strings and integers which contains the database data into another activity...I don't know how to put the database data on the string array

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to retrieve data from the table

```
public List<String[]> getData(String query) throws SQLException{

  Cursor c = mdb.rawQuery(query, null);
  c.moveToFirst();
  List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

  if (c != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) { // iterate rows
      String[] row = new String[c.getColumnCount()];
      for(int j = 0; j < c.getColumnCount(); j++){//iterate columns
        row[j] = c.getString(j);
      }
    data.add(row);
    c.moveToNext();
    }
  }
  c.close();

  Log.i("getData", data.size() + " rows returned");
  return data;
}
```

Each row of the result will be contained in each `String[]` of the list.

Say, `intentData` is a `String[]` and you want to pass the data to the next activity.For this, you have to add the data to the `Intent` like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentAct.this, NextAct.class);
intent.putExtra("dbData", intentData);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can retrieve the data from `NextAct`'s onCreate() method like this :

String[] passedData = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("dbData");